# Change background color of button in silverlight 5 in code behind

Tags: silverlight, button, colors, background

I would like to change the background color of a button when I click on it. To make the button go from Red to Green to Red, etc...

However, when I click the background color doesn't change.

Here is what I have tried :

```
button4.Background.SetValue(BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)); -> catastrophic error

button4.SetValue(BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)); -> nothing

button4.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); -> nothing
```

3rd solution seems the most revelant but doesn't work.

Comment: Both the 2nd and 3rd solution work fine for me out of the box (Silverlight 5). Have you made any changes to the button template? Also, you should be aware that even when it works the change will be quite subtle. The button background will only take on a slight pink hue. This is due to the default template for the Button class being implemented the way it is.

Comment: ok, thank you. Is there any way to change how it is implemented ? Or should I move to another solution like using an imagebutton ?

Comment: Yes, you have to edit the button template. The best way of doing this is by using Blend. Here is an article on how to build a round button template in Blend: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64937/Building-Better-Buttons-in-Expression-Blend-Silver

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in imagebutton in silverlight.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem with UserControl in Silverlight 5.

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
  Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); //nothing
}
```

But if I name the main Grid grid and write down these code:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
  grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); //ok
}
```

It works, I do not know why. When I need to use some complex opacity effects maybe I need some extra Rectangles and set their Fill. It's a little inconvenient.